# SQL not NULL(no default value) but allowed to insert NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table nonulls col1 varchar NULL col2 numeric (24,6) NOT NULL.

How can I insert value like this,

```
INSERT INTO nonulls (col1) SELECT 'ARF' as col1
```

Without having value for col2, some existing command in some of SSIS package here have that kind like of query but the col2 is not null but it still proceeds inserting value. Without using "coalesce" and without changing NOT NULL to "allow null".

Comment: What are you trying to do? Insert one row or several rows?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "_Write a title that summarizes the specific problem_".

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but if you want to insert to nonulls you need to specify values for col2 as col2 cannot be null

Comment: Well if you don't want NULL and you don't specify a default, then what value do you want?

Comment: As @jarlh mentions, please edit the title to summarize your specific problem.

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Answer (score 0):

If `col2` has a default value, then you can insert a row with no value.  It would be declared something like:

```
col2 <type> not null default <default value>
```

The default default value is `NULL`, which a `not null` declaration would preclude.

It is also possible that the table has an insert trigger defined on it.  The trigger could assign a value to the column.

Comment: hi @gordon linoff, col2 has no default value. But the previous programmer was able to insert NULL value to col2,  i dont know how